# refactoring several if else statements

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a method that I'm looking to refactor, and I know there is potential in refactoring it, but I'm quite uncertain on how it should be done most effectively.

```
  # Collection of Users questions
  def all_questions
    current_week = Time.zone.now.strftime('%V').to_i

    # biweekly
    odd_or_even_week = current_week.odd? ? 'odd_weeks' : 'even_weeks'

    # monthly
    beginning_week_of_month =
      Time.zone.now.beginning_of_month.strftime('%V').to_i
    end_week_of_month       =
      Time.zone.now.end_of_month.strftime('%V').to_i

    # quarter
    beginning_week_of_quarter =
      Time.zone.now.beginning_of_quarter.strftime('%V').to_i
    end_week_of_quarter       =
      Time.zone.now.end_of_quarter.strftime('%V').to_i

    # User's current week questions
    group_questions.weekly + questions.weekly +
      questions.send(odd_or_even_week.to_sym) +
      group_questions.send(odd_or_even_week.to_sym) +
    if current_week == beginning_week_of_month    then questions.start_of_month   + group_questions.start_of_month        else [] end +
    if current_week == end_week_of_month          then questions.end_of_month     + group_questions.end_of_month          else [] end +
    if current_week == beginning_week_of_quarter  then questions.start_of_quarter + group_questions.start_of_quarter      else [] end +
    if current_week == end_week_of_quarter        then questions.end_of_quarter   + group_questions.end_of_quarter        else [] end
  end
```

this is my method. What I'm essentially doing is checking if the current week matches one of several criterias which have been assigned to the different variables. If current week matches then I want to add an array to the list.

Some smaller issues I'm having with refactoring say the if else statements are that if I don't have a fallback on false being an empty array, then in the concatenation I'll have two ++ next to each-other because it will get the previous array, and if the one is empty in the midle add the + operator for that array. Thus resulting in an array.

question and group_questions are associations, the method called on them are enums that looks like this on the Question model:

```
  enum frequency: { weekly: 0, odd_weeks: 1, even_weeks: 2,
                    start_of_month: 3, end_of_month: 4,
                    start_of_quarter: 5, end_of_quarter: 6 }
```

Does anybody have a take on how they'd refactor this?

Comment: `questions` and `group_questions` are associations?  What are the methods called on them? scopes?

Comment: questions and group_questions are associations yes.  The method called on them are enums. I'll update my original post to make that more clear

Comment: I'd group all the questions queries together and all the group questions together.  I'd also consider creating an object that simply works out which questions to have and returns them.

Comment: yeah I agree - that's essentially what I'd like to accomplish, yet I don't see the structural way to achieve this (lack of knowledge).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def enums_required
  # do all time calculations here
  frequency_values = [Conversation.frequency[:weekly]] # always want weekly status
  frequency_values << Conversation.frequency[odd_or_even_week] 
  frequency_values << Conversation.frequency[:start_of_month] if current_week == beginning_week_of_month
  frequency_values << Conversation.frequency[:end_of_month] if current_week == end_week_of_month
  frequency_values << Conversation.frequency[:start_of_quarter] if current_week == beginning_week_of_quarter
  frequency_values << Conversation.frequency[:end_of_quarter] if current_week == end_week_of_quarter
  frequency_values
end
```

Don't do this

```
odd_or_even_week = current_week.odd? ? 'odd_weeks' : 'even_weeks'
```

Then call `.to_sym`

Just write a symbol

```
odd_or_even_week = current_week.odd? ? :odd_weeks : :even_weeks
```

Now in your method you should be able to do

```
freq = enums_required
group_questions.where(frequency: freq) + questions.where(frequency: freq)
```

Might be off on that bit, been a while since I used enums in rails.  This is basically an intermediate refactoring to get you on your way, it's by no means finished into the best it could be.